# Exchange webservice

Tags: asp.net, exchangewebservices

I am losing my mind with this as it is the last bit of an application for sending an appointment via exchange webservices and asp.net.

The are 2 error depending which piece of code i use:So if i use:

```
   service.AutodiscoverUrl("Admin@test.com");
```

I get the error:`"The account does not have permission to impersonate the requested user"`

If i use

```
    service.Url = new Uri("https://test.com/OWA/Exchange.asmx")
```

I get the error"The request failed. `The remote server returned an error: (440) Login Timeout.`"

I can login fine on the web outlook with the account so i know it works and i also can receive emails from the application when using System.NEt.mail

```
                 public static void SendOutLookAppointment(string email)
    {

        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
       // //service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("Admin@test.com"", "password");

        //service.AutodiscoverUrl("Admin@test.com");

        service.Url = new Uri("https://webmail.test.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

        //service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("Admin@test.com"", "password");
        //service.AutodiscoverUrl("Admin@test.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

        ImpersonatedUserId i = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "project.management@za.man-mn.com");
        service.ImpersonatedUserId = i;

        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
        appointment.Subject = "Calendar booking via WebService";
        appointment.Body = "This is a test";
        appointment.Start = new DateTime(2014,02,03, 21, 0, 0);
        appointment.End = new DateTime(2014,02,02,22,0, 0);

        appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(email);


         appointment.Save();
    }
```

Comment: Read this..May help http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015567

Comment: Hi I have read that article and Forms Authentication was already disabled.

Comment: You need to show us some more of your code, so that we can see what you are trying to do. Are you trying to access somebody else's mailbox?

Comment: I have added the code i don't know how it is added in the comments section because it says it is too long

Comment: The error "The account does not have permission to impersonate the requested user" means that "admin@test.com" is not allowed to impersonate the user "project.management@za.man-mn.com".  You need to set the right permissions to do impersonation.  See this article on how to set up impersonation rights: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb204095(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: Just to let everyone know I actually commented the section where i impersonate the user and the code worked fine.